# How to delete very specifically in this contact book code in Python?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    q = input('Press 1 to add, 2 to search, 3 to display, 4 to delete, 5 to clear contact book and 6 to quit: ')
    if q == '1':
        with open('contact.txt', 'a') as f:
            name = input('Name: ')
            phone= input('Phone: ')
            f.writelines((name, ' : ', phone, '\n'))
            print('\n')

    elif q == '2':
        with open('contact.txt', 'r') as f:
            search = input('Search: ')
            for i in f:
                if search in i:
                    print(i)
                    print('\n')
                else:
                    print('Contact not found \n')
                    break

    elif q == '3':
        with open('contact.txt', 'r') as f:
            print('The current entries in the contact book are \n')
            for i in f:
                print(i)
            print('\n')

    elif q == '4':
        name=input('Enter name to delete from contact book: ')
        print('\n')
        with open("contact.txt","r+") as f:
            new_f = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for line in new_f:
                if name not in line:
                    f.write(line)
            f.truncate()

    elif q == '5':
        with open('contact.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.truncate()
                
    else:
        break
```

Let's say, I have two contacts - J and James. I want to delete just J but with my delete code, I end up deleting Justin as well as it also has J in the start. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you willing to change the format of the file?  The way you've structured it makes it pretty hard to work with.  (I might suggest just putting it all in a JSON blob that you can read in all at once, work with in memory, and then write out all at once.)

Comment: Note that when you choose to search, it will break the loop on the first line if it doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only question about this code use:

```
    elif q == '4':
        name=input('Enter name to delete from contact book: ')
        print('\n')
        with open("contact.txt","r+") as f:
            new_f = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for line in new_f:
                if name != line.split()[0]: #Changed this line
                    f.write(line)
            f.truncate()
```

Then technically you will get only exact match with the name (commented a line I changed

line.split() - splits line and returns a list of 'str' values
line.split()[0] - will give you first full value

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You would probably save a lot of time by using a different data format than .txt

But to answer the question:
When you check the line for the name to delete, you're checking if the line contains the name, not if the name is equal to it.

Since you know the exact format of every entry you could easily use python's `split()` function to get only the name from the entry and then check for equality.

Like:

```
elif q == '4':
    name=input('Enter name to delete from contact book: ')
    print('\n')
    with open("contact.txt","r+") as f:
        new_f = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for line in new_f:
            if name != line.split(" : ")[0]: #splitting line on the seperator to Phone
                f.write(line)
        f.truncate()
```